# How to make a dynamic Filter Pipe (combining criteria) in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

What I intend to achieve in this code is to print cards through chosen filters. for example:

Categories are

Genre:

- Romance
- Thriller
- Fantasy

Status:

- pending
- on going
- hiatus

so if Romance, thriller, pending are chosen it will display those cards only.

What I achieved so far is it only display one item.

here is the code on my pipe

```
 transform(Projects: Project[], criteriaValue: any, properties: string[]): any[] {
    if (!Projects) return [];
    if (!criteriaValue) return Projects;
    debugger;
    return Projects.filter(item => {
      var itemFound: Boolean;
      for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (item[properties[i]].toLowerCase().indexOf(criteriaValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
          itemFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      return itemFound;
    });

  }
```

html:

```
 <div class="btn-row">
            <button mat-stroked-button aria-label="large icon" (click)="filterCriteria = 'Romance'"  > Romance</button>  
            <button mat-stroked-button aria-label="large icon"  (click)="filterCriteria = 'Thriller'" > Thriller</button> 
            <button mat-stroked-button aria-label="large icon"  (click)="filterCriteria = 'Fantasy'" > Fantasy</button> 
            <button mat-stroked-button aria-label="large icon"  (click)="filterCriteria = 'pending'" > pending</button> 
            <button mat-stroked-button aria-label="large icon"  (click)="filterCriteria = 'Hiatus'" > Hiatus</button> 
        </div>

<li *ngFor="let novel of (novelList | Searchfilter: searchValue | criteriafilter:filterCriteria:['Genre','Status']  )"> 

  <li>[[novel.title]]</li>
```

I am not entirely sure what to put on my component so it does what I intend to do. thanks in advance for the help :D

**EDIT:**

This is what I've done so far but I am getting an error on .toString

pipe:

```
 transform(Projects: Project[], criteriaValue: [], properties: []): any {
    criteriaValue.forEach((name, index) => {
      if (name) {
        Projects = Projects.filter((item) => {
          return (item[properties[index]]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(name.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        });
      }
    });
    return Projects;
  }
```

I changed my html *ngFor to:

```
<div  fxFlex= " (100/3) %" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm = 33% *ngFor="let project of (cardList | Searchfilter: searchValue | criteriafilter: [sectorCriteria, timeHorCriteria] : ['sectors','time_horizon']  )">
```

as you can see I am trying to plot the criteria to an array but I can't seem to do it right.

any kind of help is highly appreciated.

the error is

> Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: God damn it I'm stupid.. I fixed it! I just added any[] on criteriaValue  and properties

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by just adding any[] like this:

```
transform(Projects: Project[], criteriaValue: any[], properties: any[]): any {
        criteriaValue.forEach((name, index) => {
          if (name) {
            Projects = Projects.filter((item) => {
              return (item[properties[index]]
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(name.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
            });
          }
        });
        return Projects;
      }
```

Comment: I recommend getting out of the habit of using any everywhere - typescript is your friend, time spent explicitly putting types will save headaches later

Comment: oh ok thanks will do :D